# Falling object with acceleration in canvas like in gravity environment?

Tags: c#, win-universal-app

I have a canvas with border inside

```
<Canvas x:Name="mainCanvas" ManipulationMode="None" Margin="0,12,0,0" MinHeight="400">
     <Border x:Name="manipulateMe" Background="LightGray" Height="200" Width="200"  ManipulationMode="All"/>
</Canvas>
```

I already implemented manipulation function on it. Then I need it always falling down like things on air. Is there any simple way?

Beside, I also want handle the animation when it touch the ground : bounce, rolling ... base on its shape. Do I need a game engine, framework or some thing like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**Physics XAML Helper**](https://physicshelperxaml.codeplex.com/) is what I need.

Answer (score 2):

> Then I need it always falling down like things on air.

If you just want a falling down effect, you could animate the element with [`TranslateTransform`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.TranslateTransform) to along Y coordinate. For example:

```
<StackPanel Margin="15">
   <StackPanel.Resources>
       <Storyboard x:Name="myStoryboard">
           <DoubleAnimation
               RepeatBehavior="Forever"
               Storyboard.TargetName="myTranslateTransform"
               Storyboard.TargetProperty="Y"
               From="0"
               To="360"
               Duration="0:0:5" />
       </Storyboard>
   </StackPanel.Resources>
   <Rectangle
       Width="50"
       Height="50"
       Fill="RoyalBlue"
       PointerPressed="StartAnimation">
       <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
           <TranslateTransform x:Name="myTranslateTransform"  />    
       </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
   </Rectangle>
</StackPanel>

private void StartAnimation(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    myStoryboard.Begin();
}
```

More details about transform please reference [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/graphics/transforms-overview).

> Beside, I also want handle the animation when it touch the ground : bounce, rolling ... base on its shape.

For bounce effects you could use [`BounceEase`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.media.animation.bounceease), one of the [Easing functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/graphics/key-frame-and-easing-function-animations#easing-functions). For rolling you could use [`RotateTransform`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.RotateTransform) combine with `TranslateTransform`. For how to combine two animations please reference [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/graphics/storyboarded-animations#defining-more-than-one-animation-in-a-storyboard).

For a conclusion, you can find many animations you want in UWP animation library. Please reference [Animations overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/graphics/animations-overview). If this cannot meet your requirements, you may consider to use [Composition animations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/composition/composition-animation). For samples you can reference [WindowsUIDevLabs](https://github.com/Microsoft/WindowsUIDevLabs).

Comment: @sunteen-wu-msft Because I can use hand to move shape to any where in canvas, and it always fall down when hand release, sometime I can catch it when falling. Beside the acceleration is a problem too.

Comment: @sunteen-wu-msft I see the Basic Input sample on UWP doc, so I wonder how we get number of touch point when touching?

Comment: @quangkid, "I wonder how we get number of touch point when touching" I'm sorry I'm confused about what this mean.

Comment: @sunteen-wu-msft My English is not good enough to explain clearly. Really sorry! I found the example about above : https://thumbmunkeys.com/blog/news/detect-number-fingers-windows-store-applications/

Comment: @quangkid, so you have already resolved, right? And it seems this is a new issue you could open a new thread if you still have new issues.